# Applying colormap to grayscale tiff image using java

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, colortable

I have a gray scale tiff image.Now i want to add some pseudo colors i.e for pixels whose DN from 0-140, red color;DN from 141-255 ,blue color.Please tell me how to modify the raster table.Otherwise if you have any other solution,please let me know.It is urgently required for my project....